# RDLC Expression

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am creating one Invoice Report .rdlc using visual basic what I am trying to do is group wise calculation like Please guide me with this

Example:

[image]

Tried adding datasource for VAT calculation but for amount column I am not getting any results in rdlc as for vat I am getting values in my rdlc

```
Dim connstring0 As String = String.Format("Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;Username=postgres;Password=Maestro;Database=IMS_DB;")
                Dim conn0 As NpgsqlConnection = New NpgsqlConnection(connstring0)
                conn0.Open()
                Dim Command0 As NpgsqlCommand = New NpgsqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT total_vat_onsales,SUM(amount) From invoice_withvat_table Where invoice_number = 'I20160711165711' GROUP BY total_vat_onsales", conn0) '(Select MAX(CAST(id AS bigint)) from  invoice_withvat_table)
                'MessageBox.Show("SELECT DISTINCT total_vat_onsales,SUM(CAST(amount As numeric(18,2))) From invoice_withvat_table Where invoice_number = '" + vb_inviceno + "' GROUP BY total_vat_onsales")
                Dim reader0 As NpgsqlDataReader = Command0.ExecuteReader()
                Dim data_Table10 As New DataTable
                data_Table10.Load(reader0)
                reader0.Close()
                conn0.Close()
                ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
                ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DisplayName = "Invoice With VAT"
                ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Invoice_WithVAT.rdlc"
                Dim rds As ReportDataSource
                rds = New ReportDataSource("DataSet1", data_Table1)
                Dim rds0 As ReportDataSource
                rds0 = New ReportDataSource("DataSet2", data_Table10)
                ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds)
                ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds0)
                Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
```

[After Modification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSmsB.png)

It gets in rdlc but what to do next o achieve further

Comment: Instead of trying to do the calculation on the report, another approach which you may find easier to implement is to create a second datasource for the VAT analysis and totals. That way you are doing all the calculations in code and just using the report to display the results. Design a class that does the VAT work and has the subtotals as properties, then bind this to the VAT section of the report.

Comment: I have edited my question tried aading the datasource but not getting results in rdlc as for amount column

Comment: Give alias to `SUM(amount)` - So make some changes in your code like `SUM(amount) Amount From invoice_withvat_table` - By making this change, you should have data in Amount Column. let me know if it helps.

Comment: It works but I want to SUM total amount from dataset1 to amount of dataset 2 like image shown in my question "After Modification"

Answer (score 1):

You must have to play with ReportItems.

[image]

As per your Image, you should do something like below.

**1** - `=SUM(Fields!Amount.Value)`

**2** - `=(SUM(Fields!Amount.Value)/10)`

**3** - `=SUM(Fields!Amount.Value)`

*Here, Sum.Value and Div.Value are Values from 1 output and 2 output. Same way you can do further calculations.*

Comment: 10,12.5 these values are not fix they may vary

Comment: then you can take it from field property or parameter value. Show us your data structure.

Comment: I have one table with two columns VAT and Amount

Comment: How these values are vary? 12.5, 10? Please give Clear idea about question.

Comment: Entries in TABLE for VAT column is user definable. Any value as well as repeat value may come in the dataset